# segger j-link not connect to STM32F030F4P6

Tags: stm32, j-link

I use segger j-link v8, I believe programmer is true,because I could programmer stm32vldiscovery board with stm32f100rb cpu ([by this help](https://www.segger.com/downloads/appnotes/AN00021_ConnectJLinkToSTM32-DiscoveryBoards.pdf))
but when I try to connct STM32F030F4P6(TSSOP20) ,it fails.. [image]  I guess there is problem on VTref pin(pin 1 on jlink), where this pin must connect to? Which pin of stm32?

**update:**

> You see in the log that the J-Link sees 2,5V as your board power supply. Is that correct?

yes, it is. but I am confused, may I ask you what is that pin that VTref must connect(in the image)??[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see in the log that the J-Link sees 2,5V as your board power supply. Is that correct?

Vtref supplies output buffers of the programmer (to support different voltages). You should connect this line to the same supply voltage as you target microcontroller uses for its pins (commonly 3,3V).